# Import an existing SVN project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a folder on the C drive which is already checked out from SVN. In somewhere in that folder, I have an Eclipse project folder. It is already in the SVN repository.

I started Eclipse, imported that project, but I am not sure how to connect it to SVN. When I was working on a [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) repository, Eclipse CVS discovered its setting when I tried to share it. How can I do this with Subversion?

Answer (score 8):

This is how it's done with Subclipse. If I remember correctly, the process is similar in Subversive because they both use the Team API.

Right-click on the project, select **Team** -> **Share Project...**

Then select SVN as the SCM provider, then follow the wizard to completion.

According to this [installation guide](http://wiki.webratio.com/index.php/Installing_Subversion), Subversion does follow the same approach. If you haven't already set up your Subversion repository, the Wizard will prompt you to do so as in the screenshot below. The settings are the same as you would ordinarily use to connect to Subversion.

[Share project wizard screenshot http://wiki.webratio.com/images/0/01/SpecifyRepository.png](http://wiki.webratio.com/images/0/01/SpecifyRepository.png)

Comment: I did what Rich Seller did and I was running into the problem where it still couldn't connect to it. You have you make sure that your project root directory is the one that contains the *.svn folders.

Comment: Yes, be careful with this. I had the SVN root wrong and it managed to check in a folder at the wrong level before crapping out. Took a while to fix as there was some discrepancy with SVN versions :(

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the project name to bring up the context menu. Select Team -> Share Project...

See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/faq.php#checked) in the Subversive FAQ.