# How to Create Eclipse Project from SVN Working Copy

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I don't want to checkout a new project and i don't wan't to use the share function.

what i want to do is: i already have a folder in my eclipse workspace which is an svn working copy. i just want to import it as a project from disk so eclipse knows it's connected to svn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is NOT possible! -.-

Comment: I really whish it would be... And it is - With Team->Share

Answer (score 0):

Add the project to your workspace as you would any other project then use share. I know you said you don't want to, but despite sounding like it will share it as a new project in SVN it does what you want in this case where the project already has SVN metadata in it.

Comment: well it then asks for the repository location and it won't work with every project. also i takes very long to use the share project function. also it will checkout the whole project again to a temp folder (whyever) but all information is already in the .svn folders. it's a very bad soloution imo. there should be a function, "import working copy from disk" or simply a function to detect existing .svn and .git etc...

Comment: Well, if this isn't working I'm not sure what other options you have. I agree there should be an explicit way to deal with this but I don't think there is.

Here's another similar question that seems to indicate the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265549/import-an-existing-svn-project-into-eclipse

Comment: so it seems there isn't a a soloution for this problem until eclipse devs add that feature -.-